# Can an unavailable datasource take down a ColdFusion 9 server?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Is it possible that a database (connected to ColdFusion 9 via a datasource connection) being unavailable could cause ColdFusion to become unresponsive? (The database is used for a singular one-off lightly-trafficked app.)

Recently, maintenance on a connected Oracle database (oracle jdbc) has caused that database to be unavailable two different times. Coincidentally, at both these times, ColdFusion pages on our site became unavailable or terribly slow to load (static HTML pages seemed to load fine, for the most part).  Restarting the ColdFusion application server service would fix the problem, but only for minutes.  The first time, during a time the application server was responsive, we unchecked the "Maintain connections" checkbox.  I'm not sure this had any effect, then shortly after the Oracle database came back online, and we didn't seem to have the problem any more.

The second time that database was offline, we experienced a very similar issue with our website - ColdFusion pages becoming reaaaally slow or unavailable altogether.  During one of the times when I could access the CF administrator, I updated the datasource and checked "Disable connections".  Then I stopped and restarted both the CF ODBC agent and ODBC server services.  After that, the problem seemed to stop, but I don't know enough to know if this is causation or coincidence.

Anyone have insights on this?

Server setup: Windows Server 2003 SP2, ColdFusion 9, IIS 6

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to slow a database to a crawl if not stop it completely.  If you have hackers for example attacking your database through Port 1433 with attempted logins several times a second that can slow it down and if they get in they can of course do whatever they want.  When this happened to me I found a record of attacks in the Event logs; the solution is better network security intercepting such attacks and never letting them actually talk to the database.  Or say if your site is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks hackers could be messing with your database that way too but network security wouldn't necessarily work in that case.  It doesn't require hackers to degrade the performance of your database however, you could be having a problem with allocated disk space for transaction logs or indexes filling up, or heaven forbid an imminent hardware failure showing early symptoms.  You're backing up your database often I hope, off the server.  To answer your question yes ColdFusion can and will become unresponsive when pages are called that call the database, and will usually display error messages when the database finally times out and never sends the requested data to ColdFusion.  You can protect against that to some extent with CFTRY tags around your queries that display clean and polite error messages instead of ColdFusion's ugly ones if the database fails to return data, at least your site continues to look professional that way.  One project I worked used a shared SQL Server database that often got overloaded and slowed down terribly and there was nothing I could do about improving that situation.  What I did to keep the site functioning was to maintain a DB backup in the form of a MS Access database (yeah it was inappropriate but it worked when SQL Server wouldn't) and anytime SQL Server failed I had the application set up to automatically use code that called the Access database instead.

These are some ideas for you to think about if you are continuing to have problems, I see nobody's even tried to answer your question in the last six months and that's kinda been my experience with the quality of assistance this site has offered me too.  I hope my thoughts can be of some use to you.